# Extract numbers from a string in python without the use of isdigit or re. tools

Tags: python, string, input, int

Let's say I have a string of integers generated by user input, where each integer is separated by a space (Code below for example)...

How can I search through that string and store each integer separately for use later on in the program? (I.E. Assigning each integer to its own variable) I can't use isdigit and cant use re tools, and I can't store the ints into a list.

```
 userEntry = input("Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature: ")

for i in range(4):
    userEntry += " " + input("Please enter another fahrenheit:")
```

Things I AM allowed to use: string methods, index find/search methods, for loops, if statements, while loops.

Comment: Store your ints in a list.

Comment: I am not allowed to use a list, either..Updated the post to reflect that spec.

Comment: You are not using lists from your previous question onwards. If in future user has to enter some 100 fahrenheits, do you intend to use 100 variables?

Comment: Are you allowed to use dictionaries?

Comment: Instead of using isdigit, you could see if it's `in "0123456789"` or `in {"0", "1", ...}`

Comment: You have to be more specific as to how you want the variables stored. Do you want each stored as a seperate global variable or do you just want a function which accesses integer in some indexes position by searching through the userEntry?

Comment: "... Things I AM allowed to use: string methods...", but `str.isdigit` is a string method

Comment: Your teacher isn't lame: he wants you to create a funxtion which loops on tbe input string and yields each number

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your use case is, and I can not think of a way where you can assign the numbers to variable in a loop, which is what you have to do if you are not allowed to use a loop. The only way I can think of is `exec` and I do not feel that is allowed for your task. Regardless, I am posting the answer, in case it is usable:

```
last_space_index = 0
characters_checked = 0
var_num = 1
userEntry = "12.8 -15.8 125.9 0 -40.0"
for character in userEntry:
    characters_checked += 1
    if character == ' ':
        number = float(userEntry[last_space_index:characters_checked])
        var_name = 'var'+str(var_num)
        var_num += 1
        expression = var_name + ' = number'
        # expression becomes 'var1 = number'
        exec(expression)
        last_space_index = characters_checked
last_number = float(userEntry[last_space_index:])
var_name = 'var'+str(var_num)
expression = var_name + ' = last_number'
exec(expression)
# if you know the number of variables you are going to get
print(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)
# else:
# for i in range(1,var_num+1):
#    var_name = 'var'+str(i)
#    command = 'print('+var_name+')'
#    exec(command)
```

Output:

```
>>> 12.8  -15.8  125.9  0  -40.0
```

You can replace print with whatever you actually want to do.
And this is completely futile if you are allowed to use dictionary, sets or tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will parse the string into space-separated strings, using slices... (I notice the first answer came in while I was working on this, but this is slightly different, so...)

```
def extractor(mystr):
    start = 0
    for a in range(len(mystr)):
        if mystr[a] == ' ' or mystr[a] == len(mystr) - 1:
            temp = mystr[start:a]
            print(temp)
            start = a + 1
```

This is more like a C approach, very un-Pythonic, but standard programming fare. If you will only ever have 5 user entries, this is perhaps manageable. If you can't use a list of those variables, or if you have an unknown number of user entries, or if you have to check to make sure the user actually entered a digit and not a letter, then more work is required, but that's the basic C-string parser. Useful to know if you ever want to dive into Python internals I suppose.

If you need to convert each extracted string to an int, and exceptions are allowed, place this inside the if statement to check for type correctness:

```
try:
    myvar1 = int(temp)
except ValueError:
    print("Not an int")
```

Note that if you absolutely cannot use lists, (*or exec as in the above answer) then the only likely option is to keep slicing off the end of the string, i.e you'd have to do something like the following at the end of each if statement, then write that for loop out 4 more times, changing the variable name each time manually.

```
mystr = mystr[start:len(mystr)]
break
```

This will of course not work if you have a variable number of user entries. And is incredibly tedious... I suspect the instructor may have intended something different. Note that the real-world process for all that is just:

```
result = [int(x) for x in mystr.split(' ') if x.isdigit()]
```